# Expat Xbox gaming

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I've just recently moved to then Netherlands from the U.S.. The only device that's really given me trouble so far is our Xbox 360 slim. The power supply is 110-only and the converter I bought for it can't really handle it (goes for about 40 minutes then overheats). I'm considering buying a new 360 here, but I'd rather not because I can't be sure that my games I brought from the states will work.

I can't find any 220-volt power supplies for 360 slims that get decent reviews and don't really know how much power the thing draws to help me pick a higher-capacity converter.

Does anyone have any advice for a gamer in a strange land? Where to get a European PS? How much power to spec in a converter?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, guys! I tried to find that answer, but was obviously searching for the wrong terms. Let me edit this to focus on the power portion of the question...

Comment: The Xbox 360 consoles are region-locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consult Microsoft's [support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console-power/power-supply) (under "AC power cords") about this.

You'll notice that you need a PSU that is compatible with a **230v @ 50Hz** outlet for the Netherlands, which should be compatible with your NTSC Slim console (whose PSU is made for a 120v @ 60Hz outlet) because the DC output is the same (look at your PSU).

**NTSC:** AC input: 100-127v-3.7A, 47.63 MHz, DC output: 135 watts

**PAL:** AC input: 200-240v-2A, 47.63 MHz, DC output: 135 watts

It's recommend contacting [Xbox 360 support](http://support.xbox.com/contact-us) and asking for a "replacement," checking your local game/electronics store, or even Ebay.